# Alternative to `file-name-extension` that will include `~`

Tags: string

I am looking for an alternative to `file-name-extension` that will include an ending `~` if there is one.  For example, if there is a file named `foo.el~`, the result should be `el~`.

Rather than using the generic `split-string`, I was hoping there might be something more specific geared towards file extensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in function `file-name-extension` uses `file-name-sans-versions`, which does us the *favor* of removing the **tilde**.  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Name-Components.html  Removing `file-name-sans-versions` from said function achieves the desired effect.

```
(defun my-file-name-extension (filename &optional period)
"This function is a modification of `file-name-extension`, in that the function
`file-name-sans-extensions` has been removed -- thus, the tilde (if any) remains."
  (save-match-data
    (let ((file (file-name-nondirectory filename)))
      (if (and (string-match "\\.[^.]*\\'" file)
        (not (eq 0 (match-beginning 0))))
          (substring file (+ (match-beginning 0) (if period 0 1)))
        (if period
            "")))))
```